# Slide down animation to display errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I need help with the slide down animation that Facebook has on iOS that shows errors. In the attached image, it's the view that says "No Internet Connection" in white text on a black background.

It seems to slide down to display an error message, and after a while it slides back up. What is it called, and how can I implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/), it contains custom controls for ios and Mac OS X (free and commercial).

Some notification classes for iOS:

[JSNotifier](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsnotifier)

[MessageBarManager](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/messagebarmanager)

[TSMessages](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tsmessages)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a stock UI component, so it doesn't have a name.

If you want to replicate the same functionality you have to implement it on your own.

It doesn't look complicated though: a simple `UILabel` and an animation block should do the trick.